# SSL certificate on cluster server

Tags: ssl, web-server, cluster

could you please advice how to apply SSL certs on web servers behind a load balance server.
Do we need to apply SSL certs on all the web servers or apply it to the load balancer only.

scenario:
if we have three web servers say www1, www2, www3  behind a load balance server.do we need to apply SSL certs on www1, www2 and www3??

Comment: What kind of load balancer?  Are you looking to have the load balancer terminate SSL and send unencrypted traffic to the servers behind it, or have it just proxy raw TCP connections and have the web servers terminate the SSL connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do either. The certificate vendors should have instructions on their web sites for generating keys and CSRs and installing certificates on various web servers and load balancers. Note that the type of certificate needed may vary. You might also want to configure session stickiness, and note that SNI might not be available on very old browsers (which in practice means ie6).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you will have to just setup https on your load balancer with **[Server Name Indication](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni)**. For example, you can use [nginx](http://nginx.org/) as SSL reverse proxy for your sites ([very good guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-setup-nginx-ssl-proxy/)).